# Retrieving data from Messaging queue

Tags: ibm-mq

public string WriteMsg(string strInputMsg)
        {
            string strReturn = "";

```
        try
        {
            MQQueue queue = null;
            MQQueueManager QueueManagerName = null ;

            QueueManagerName = new MQQueueManager("GRBAAQM");
            queue = QueueManagerName.AccessQueue(QueueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT
                + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            message = strInputMsg;
            queueMessage = new MQMessage();

            queueMessage.WriteString(message);
            queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;

            queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);

            strReturn = "Message sent to the queue successfully";
  }

        catch (MQException MQexp)
        {
            strReturn = "Exception: " + MQexp.Message;
        }

        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            strReturn = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
        }

        return strReturn;
       }

    public string ReadMsg()
    {
        String strReturn = "";

        try
        {
            MQQueue queue = null;
            MQQueueManager QueueManagerName = null;

            QueueManagerName = new MQQueueManager("GRBAAQM");
            queue = QueueManagerName.AccessQueue(QueueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF +
                MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            queueMessage = new MQMessage();
            queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;

            queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);

            strReturn =

            queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
        }

        catch (MQException MQexp)
        {
            strReturn = "Exception : " + MQexp.Message;
        }

        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            strReturn = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
        }

        return strReturn;
    }
```

These two methods in this program helps us to read the messages from queue and displays but how to insert this feature while reading message FROM queue, read only if the message count has reached 10.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care how many messages are in the queue?  MQ is NOT a database.  If a message is in the queue then it should be processed.  If you need to group messages together then have the sender use MQ's message grouping feature.

Did you read about MQ triggering?  A program can be triggered (started) based on a triggering event.  i.e. Trigger-first, trigger-every & trigger-depth.